# Why Apache IoTDB cannot be connected locally while the access of public network can be executed normally?

Tags: database, time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

Now, my Apache IoTDB server (Version 1.1.0 standalone) is deployed on cloud using docker, and IoTDB can be used when access to the ip of public network connection inside the server. Howver, IoTDB cannot be connected locally when the port is open. The error information is: `org.apache.iotdb.rpc.IoTDBConnectionException: Fail to reconnect to server. Please check server status.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:6667`. Why IoTDB cannot be connected in this case and how can I successfully connect it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to change port from `6667` to another port and see if this failure still appears in Apache IoTDB, it should be solved.